# str_replace with $_GET value and query results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace my query result according to the `$_GET` value like

If I have URL like
`URL/?userid=3255`

then the output of the userid from the database should replace with `$_GET` value when printing the database data

PS: I don't want to update the userid in database i just want to replace userid on the front end when printing the data from database
database table:

```
userid     | name
-----------|
userid=4332|ron
```

Code:

```
<?php str_replace("userid=","userid=echo $_GET['userid'],"$row['userid']);?>
```

$row['userid'] is the data that i fetch from the database

Comment: can make new url directly like `"url_value/id?".$_GET['id']`, no?

Comment: Why not simply assign the value to your fetched data: `$row['userid']=$_GET['userid']`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to fetch only the row matching that `userid` value? If so, that's a `WHERE userid=?` thing. Are you trying to compose a query string? Use concatenation or `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
<?php str_replace("userid=","userid=".$_GET['userid'], $row['userid']);?>
```

but if user changes $_GET['userid'] param printed result will also change according to the new userid param.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the url that return an associative array. Then use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) that parse the string into variables. Make any changes you need. Then reassemble the address with the changes using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/?userid=3255';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);

if(isset($parsed_str['userid']))
{
  // make any changes you want
  $parsed_str['userid'] = "new id"; 

  // reassemble the address with the changes
  $link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/?";
  $http_builded = $link . http_build_query($parsed_str);
}
```

I hope this can help you.